# Reading Appsetting in AppModule - Angular 8

Tags: json, angular, typescript, module, configuration

I have some configuration in my appsetting, I would change an hardcode string and make the appModule reading from appsetting. That's my hardcode in appmodule.ts:

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
  apiKey: 'testtesttest',
  libraries: ['places']
}),
```

and this is my section in appsetting.json:

```
  "Geocode": {
    "apiKey": {
      "key": "testtesttest"
    }
  }
```

How can I make it work like this?

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
  apiKey: appsetting.Geocode.apiKey.key,
  libraries: ['places']
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

Set these in your `tsconfig.json` ([documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#new---resolvejsonmodule))

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
```

And you should be able to do:

```
import appsetting from './appsetting.json'
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
  apiKey: appsetting.Geocode.apiKey.key,
  libraries: ['places']
}),
```